# Opening MapInfo .TAB file containing text objects in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, convert, mapinfo, tab

Whenever I try to open a MapInfo .TAB file that contains text objects in QGIS, the text objects are converted to point objects.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QGIS doesn't support text objects from TAB files.  You can label the points in QGIS using the advanced label options.

Pro Tip: Look at using **map units** for you label sizing to match how they look in MapInfo.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use MapInfo Universal Translator, you can translate your layers to DWG. Then you should import this DWG in QGIS. In the finish you will get your text in .gpkg format retaining symbology of text objects (including the colour, orientation and size of font). This approach is good enough.
If you haven't MapInfo Universal Translator, you can also use geospatial data online converter:
https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/
choose input and output data formats
[image]
But there is a limitation 5 MB per month for geospatial data convertion.
A feature request to add ability to import into QGIS the text objects from MapInfo .TAB and .MIF formats is already created on Github:
[Ability to import text objects from .TAB and .MIF formats](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44712)